Prove that $\int_0^l [v_j(x)]^2dx=2$ and $\int_0^l v_j(x)v_{j+1}(x)dx=-1$
Given an interval [0, $l$], and $l$ is an integer.
Define trial function $v_j(x)=1-j+x$, for $j-1≤x≤j$ ; $v_j(x)=1+j-x$, for $1≤x≤j+1$; $v_j(x)=0$ elsewhere. (In other words, $v_j(j)=1$ and $v_j(k)=0$, for j≠k, and $v_j(x)$ is continuous).
Assume that j, k are all positive integers.
How to prove that $\int_0^l [v_j(x)]^2dx=2$ and $\int_0^l v_j(x)v_{j+1}(x)dx=-1$ ??
I have tried to calulate the integral, but I only got $\frac23$ and $\frac16$, respectively.
Thanks for help.

Do you mean $v_j(x) = 1+ j -x$ for $j\leq x\leq j+1$? Also, if $l$ is any integer this is clearly not true...

Your $v_j$ are always nonnegative so I don't understand how the integral could be negative.

Oh sorry, i forget to define.  $l=N*1$, and $j=1, 2, 3,..., N$. Also, $N=l-1$.

Actually, it's excercise $3$ in Strauss PDE, chapter $8.5$. I'm also confused about it. But the excercise is necessary for further discussion...
